# Insert a value into a row in datagrid vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I'm currently stuck on inserting a value into a row in `datagridview` in `vb.net`

My code is:

```
Dim subtotal As Integer = Val(adult.Text) * 500 + Val(child.Text) * 300

                    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView2.Rows
                        row.Cells.Insert(subtotal)
                    Next
```

It supposed to be like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyfl7.png)

Hint [I wanna do it like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpNiA.png)

Comment: You don't insert a new cell. You get an existing cell and set its `Value` property. It seems that you need to do some more reading on how the `DataGridView` control works.

Answer (score 1):

You don't insert a new cell. You get an existing cell in the appropriate column and set its Value property. This line:

```vb
row.Cells.Insert(subtotal)
```

would be like this:

```vb
row.Cells(columnIndex).Value = subtotal
```

That said, that will put the same value in every row. That's probably not what you want but it's all we can you based on the information you've provided. If what you actually expect is to get a different value for each row based on data in that row then the calculation would have to be inside the loop as well, e.g.

```vb
Dim adultCount = CInt(row.Cells(adultColumnIndex).Value)
Dim childCount = CInt(row.Cells(childColumnIndex).Value)
Dim subtotal = adultCount * 500 + childCount * 300

row.Cells(subtotalColumnIndex).Value = subtotal
```

Of course, if you had bound this grid to a `DataTable` then you could set the `Expression` property of the `DataColumn` for the subtotal and it would be calculated automatically.